# Is the proposition "$A$ is separable and $B \subset A$ then $B$ is separable" in metric spaces true for A, B arbitrary sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

In the book Linear functional analysis by Rynne and Youngson, Second edition:

THEOREM 1.43.

Suppose that $(M, d)$ is a metric space and $A  \subset M$.

(a) If $A$ is compact then it is separable.

(b) If $A$ is separable and $B \subset A$ then $B$ is separable

**Is there something wrong in (b) of this theorem?** From the statement A and B are just sets, not necessarily metric spaces but, if so, (b) would be wrong. So to proof that B is separable I have to find a countable set that is dense in A. If the proposition is true for $M=A=\mathbb{R}$ and B any subset of A, for instance a singleton $\{x\}$, which is clearly not dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it would read that the singleton set B is separable , but I don't think so, because for that, $B=\{x\}$ should be dense in $A=\mathbb{R}$
So should I assume A and B are metric spaces instead of just sets?

Comment: No, a singleton is not dense in $\Bbb R$ So what? The theorem isn't saying anything about dense sets, it's talking about separable sets, and a singleton is obviously separable

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  Is a singleton B separable because it is dense in itself?. I thought the density was supposed to be  with respect to A, since we are talking about subsets of A

Comment: The theorem has nothing to do with B being dense in A.

Comment: A set $S$ is separable if there exists a countable set $C\subset S$ such that $\overline C=S$.

Comment: No we're not talking about subsets of $A$. The set $B\subset A$ is separable if $B$ has a countable dense subset (dense in $B$).

Comment: (b) is correct since everything is contained in a metric space $M$.  But (b) may fail for  topological spaces in general.  Similar for (a).

Comment: @GEdgar Sticking to metric spaces, If I take M=A=$\mathbb{R}$, then (b) says any subsetB  of A is separable, I am having trouble accepting  this, for instance if$ B =\{x\}$ , then it is countable, but why should it contain a dense set? I am not sure why it would be the set itself. If I take$ B=\mathbb{N}$, what would a dense set contained in it be? Again the same set?why?

Comment: $\{x\}$ is countable, and $\{x\}$ is a dense subset of $\{x\}$.  When we say "$B$ is separable", we mean $B$ has a countable subset that is dense in $B$.

Comment: If we always take the same set as the dense subset contained in it, then any finite or countably infinite set is separable?

Comment: Correct.  So proving $B$ is separable is more difficult when $B$ is uncountable.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind: in many mathematical categories, topological spaces and metric spaces included, a "sub-object" is assumed to inherit structure from the parent object, *even if this is rarely mentioned explicitly*. Thus, in any topological space $X$, a subset $A \subset X$ is assumed to inherit the subspace topology from $X$. Also, in any metric space $M$, a subset $A \subset M$ is assumed to inherit the restricted metric from $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A \subseteq M$ so $A$ is automatically treated as a metric space (and hence topological space too). To $B \subseteq A$ this also applies. We also consider $B$ as a metric space.

That the total space $M$ is metric is important because if it were only a topological space and $A,B$ would get the standard subspace topologies, the result would not necessarily hold anymore. But for metric spaces being separable is the same as having a countable base and that property *is* hereditary, whereas in general separability need not be.

Answer (score 0):

An example where it doesn't hold for a non-metrizable space would be $(X,T_p)$, where $\; T_p=\{A\subseteq X : p\in A\}\cup\{\emptyset\}$ given a $p\in X$, and $X$ an uncountable set. $(X,T_p)$ is separable because $cl(\{p\})=X$, but considering $X-\{p\}\subseteq X$, $(X-\{p\},T_p|)=(X-\{p\},T_D)$ is not separable becuase if $D\subseteq X-\{p\}$ such that $cl(D)=X-\{p\}$, then $D=X-\{p\}$ which isn't countable.